# how to access all item renderer of MX: Tree in?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

my renderer contains a canvas in it, i add some title-window, every time i see my tree previously added Title-Windows are visible, i want to access each n every item in tree and remove previosly added all windows from the rendere.
so can any tell me how access all the item renderer in AS3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if tree having id for example "**id_tree**" is using **XML** dataprovidor then by useing the

```
for each(var tmp:xml in rootTag.descendants())
{
id_tree.itemToItemRenderer(tmp);
}
```