# how to access all item renderer of MX: Tree in?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

can i access every item renderer of tree in as3 ?( **note that i am using custom item renderer**) lets say i want to add some button in canvas(children of custom itemRender)..
like

```
getItemRender().addChild();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access all item renderer of MX: Tree in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287335/how-to-access-all-item-renderer-of-mx-tree-in)

Comment: You can edit the question and add more info if you want - don't ask duplicate ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, but it is possible.

itemRenderers are stored internally in an array.  USually that array is a protected variables.  Take a look at [listItems](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#listItems) and [freeItemRenderers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#freeItemRenderers) and [highlightItemRenderer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#highlightItemRenderer).

They are all protected, so you'll have to extend the Tree class and expose them to access them.

If possible, I would strongly recommend putting values in your dataProvider and updating the itemRenderer based on that data; not trying to access itemRenderers directly.

Answer (score 0):

tree.itemToItemRenderer([item]);

Iterate through every item that's sitting in your tree's dataProvider and pass each item into that method.